# Radio buttons to images and hover over values with tooltip

Tags: css, radio-button

I am trying to make a selection using images to replace the radio buttons.

So far, I have this code which works...

```
<table width="200">
<tr>
<td><label>
<input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="111" id="RadioGroup1_0" style="display:none">
<img src="images/AddressBook-Black-128x128.png" width="128" height="128"> </label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>
<input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="222" id="RadioGroup1_1" style="display:none">
<img src="images/AddressBook-Red-128x128.png" width="128" height="128"></label></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

How do I add a orange border around the selected item?
And then add a tooltip in the middle of the image  with a black square box and with the words "red books" in white text when the selection is "hovered" over?

Altogether there are 16 items, each has a different image.

Comment: There is no `alt` attribute in each of your `img` (it's mandatory) thus your `label` is empty (no readable/parsable text). Plus by using display: none on the radio buttons, it will probably not be read by screen readers. You can style radio buttons and still be accessible and add other styles by using background-image on label, displaying them over the default radio buttons: http://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/customInput/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/zYVz8/16/

**HTML**

```
<div class="options">
    <label title="Baseball Cap">
        <input type="radio" name="foo"/>
        <img src="http://tshirtbangkok.com/wp-content/uploads/cap-baseball-100x100.jpg"/>
    </label>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.options {
    background-color: #FFF7C0;
    padding: 10px 5px 5px 10px;
}

div.options:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

div.options > label {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}

div.options > label > img {
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid #eee;
}

div.options > label > input {
    position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
}

div.options > label > input:checked + img {
    border-color: #51A351;
}
```

Comment: That was pretty cool coma.. I am trying to get it like this http://tshirtbangkok.com/quotation-form/cap-order-form/

Comment: That excellent... Ill try and figure out what you did to make that work... *still learning CSS and Divs

Comment: Dude, if you find my answer useful, please, check it as correct.

Comment: Label titles (centered in image with black box and white text) and columns (4x4) still need to be added... can the columns be done in a Table?

Comment: You don't need tables for this, just let them float and adjust the containers width. The black tooltip can be done with js or css, let me do it with css, wait...

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted... Doesnt seem to work in WP though.

Comment: It doesnt work on the site http://personalized-lanyards.com/free-quote-form/ (Its at the bottom)

Comment: oh, hi dude!, you need to include the js and css from bootstrap to get those tooltips, I'll update the jsfiddle to use only css

Comment: How can I give you extra points or something? You are very helpful!

Comment: Ok, this is the example using only CSS for tooltips http://jsfiddle.net/coma/zYVz8/25/ , but you could check some js library for tooltips, like http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/ or http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips. About the extra points... hehehe, don't worry!